# Git commit - treat # comments similar with or without message file

Tags: git

I have staged a file `readme.txt`. When invoking

```
$ git commit
```

it opens my editor with a predefined message (the `|` in the first line I've added only to force stackoverflow to show this empty line):

```
|
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   modified:   readme.txt
#
# Untracked files:
#   message.txt
#
```

so I can enter the message

```
add readme.txt
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   modified:   readme.txt
#
# Untracked files:
#   message.txt
#
```

save and exit, the commit will be created with the message `add readme.txt`.

However, when having the same content in a file `message.txt` (including the `#` lines) and running

```
$ git commit --file message.txt
```

the commit will have the full content of the file as message, including all the comments.

How to tell Git to ignore the `#` lines in the specified message file as it does without the `--file <message-file>` parameter?

Answer (score 4):

This would then be

```
git stripspace --strip-comments < message.txt |
    git commit --file -
```