# commit-msg hook reads all the data to commit_msg when amending

Tags: bash, git, githooks

In my `commit-msg` hook git passes commented lines from `amend` prompt to the script hook.

```
msg="$(cat "$1")"
```

When I am doing `git commit --amend` the output of the msg is

```
GRP-0903 CHANGE OTHER - Enhance commit-msg hook to restrict commit messages # Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting # with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit. # # Date: Sat Jan 28 19:41:37 2023 +0400 # # On branch fix/GRP-0903-Button-icons-visibility-issue # Your branch is up to date with 'origin/fix/GRP-0903-Button-icons-visibility-issue'. # # Changes to be committed: # modified: .husky/commit-msg # deleted: tools/git-hooks/pre-commit.sh #
```

This is my original commit message - `GRP-0903 CHANGE OTHER - Enhance commit-msg hook to restrict commit messages`. The rest is coming from the amending prompt.
This is the content of my editor when I am using amend.

```
GRP-0988 CHANGE OTHER - Enhance commit-msg hook to restrict commit messages

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# Date:      Sat Jan 28 19:41:37 2023 +0400
#
# On branch fix/GRP-0903-Button-icons-visibility-issue
# Your branch is up to date with 'origin/fix/GRP-0903-Button-icons-visibility-issue'.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   modified:   .husky/commit-msg
#   deleted:    tools/git-hooks/pre-commit.sh
#
```

When I do a normal commit without amending, it works fine.
How can I make git pass only commit message to the hook ?

Comment: Use the `head` utility or the builtin `read` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to get the message directly without the template, but you could emulate this by `grep`ing the commented out lines away instead of calling `cat $1`:

```bash
msg="$(grep -v '^#' $1)"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75258927/7976758 , https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stripspace

Comment: Also, if the user is using `git commit -v`, you may wish to strip out the appended text.  After examining gerrit's code, I'm going with `sed -e '/-- >8 --/q' $1 | git stripspace --strip-comments`.